# insert date in postgres database

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a day, month and year in php variables. How can I use them in a SQL INSERT statement, knowing that the field I want to insert that date is of the date type.

Thanks.

Comment: Just for reference - [a list of recognised DATE formats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format the date as a string and pass it to the SQL query

```
   $date =  sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d",$year,$month,$day)
```

where you can replace the $year, $month and $day variables with your desired input.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP's date() method and then possibly combine with strtotime() to convert to right format.